# UserDefaults Auto-Login trouble

Tags: swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I have tried everything under the sun to allow the user to stay logged in via UserDefaults. However, every time I log in, close out of the app, and open it again, the app reverts to the login screen. I have tried using the solutions from other similar questions, but none have worked.

Below is some code from my login screen when the "Log In" button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func logInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let email = firstNameTF.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = lastNameTF.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil{
            //couldnt sign in
            self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
        } else {
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                self.errorLabel.text = "Logged in"
                self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
                print("log in successful")
                self.userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: "user_uid_key")
                self.userDefaults.synchronize()
                self.transitionToHome()

            } else {
            }
        }
    }
           
}
```

Finally, here is the code from my AppDelegate:

```
var window: UIWindow?
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
        check()
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

//        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SViewController())

```
    return true
}
    func check() {
        if userDefaults.value(forKey: "user_uid_key") as? Bool == true {

            
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

Link to zip file for debug project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hd-E4yaHN70nH2wj0l9rP6xDLUC9oHEA/view?usp=sharing

New SceneDelgeate:

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    if userDefaults.value(forKey: "user_uid_key") as? Bool == true {
        print("userdefaults function is running")
        

        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
  //                        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TBCID") as! UITabBarController

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `UIWindow(frame:)` is not working as expected, starting iOS 13 you are expected to move your logic to `SceneDelegate.swift` and `UIWindow(windowScene:)`. Also please take a look at indentation and closing brackets.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Assuming the first `if` in `check()` evaluates to `true` you are doing `self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController` and `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` but when `check()` finishes you are creating a new `UIWindow` and doing `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` on this new `UIWindow`.

I think what you want to do is (tried to keep your styling):

```
var window: UIWindow?
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
        
    check()

    return true
}

func check() -> Bool {
    if userDefaults.value(forKey: "user_uid_key") as? Bool == true {
   
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
            
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TBCID") as! TBCVC

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {

        window = UIWindow()

        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SViewController())

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I tried your suggestions but the app still won't stay logged in. Is it possible that because the view controller I am instantiating, TBCVC, is a tab bar controller and not a normal view controller, the code is not executed the same? That is the only other thing that I can think of.

Comment: Are you sure `userDefaults.value(forKey: "user_uid_key") as? Bool` is `true` when `check()` runs?

Comment: I just confirmed using a print statement that `userDefaults.value(forKey: "user_uid_key") as? Bool` is true when `check()` runs. I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: I’m still stuck on this

Comment: Can you create a test project where you can reproduce this? I can't think about anything else with the information you provided sadly @MichaelStangas

Comment: I use the exact same code in a different project of mine... the only difference is that this app’s main view controller is a tab bar VC instead of a navigation VC.

Comment: There's definitely a bug in your logic, that's why I'm asking if you could upload a small project where you can reproduce this issue

Comment: I’m sorry, can you please clarify what you mean by reproduce the issue? Should I create a new project and duplicate my project that isn’t working? Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: The idea is that you provide us with a small project where that same issue is happening, that way you are not sending your project which should (I guess) be private and we can still help you with your issue. To do so just create a new project, add the logic that's not working, make sure the bug is still there, edit your question and add it there as a `.zip`

Comment: I have created the new project, made sure the bug is still there, and zipped the file. I'm sorry, but how do I add the zip file to my question?

Comment: My bad, you should upload the `.zip` somewhere and the share a link, you can use Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.

Comment: Just added the link!

Comment: @MichaelStangas great! I think you have to make it public though, I can't access it

Comment: Sorry about that! All set.

Comment: Were you able to find anything?

Comment: Found the cause, using `UIWindow(frame:)` is not working, instead move your code to `SceneDelegate:willConnectTo` and use `UIWindow(windowScene:)` to create the window, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Lastly, I am getting an error for `self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: UIScreen.main.bounds)` saying `Cannot convert value of type 'CGRect' to expected argument type 'UIWindowScene'`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `UIWindow(windowScene:)` requires you to pass a `UIWindowScene` which you will get inside the method called `willConnectTo` in `SceneDelegate`. You should have a `guard let` there, just replace the `_` next to that `let` with `windowScene` (or anything) and use that to initialize the `UIWindow`

Comment: Believe it or not it is still sending me back to the sign in page. I have added my sceneDelegate to the new post above. If everything looks OK with that, is it possible that my initial view controller (which is the tab bar controller) is wrong?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, I could run it successfully, it's not a User-Defaults issue but an issue with your logic, try removing the "Initial ViewController" from Main.storyboard and instead do it programmatically. Also if it helped you please consider upvoting

Comment: Just upvoted and checked as answer. Is there any way you could reupload the project to drive so I can download and compare with mine, since you said it works on your end? I appreciate all of your help, I was just about done with the app and this is a very frustrating issue haha.

Comment: I definitely answered your question which is the point of this site, not fix specific issues but instead provide answers that are useful for other people as well. Having said that, you’ve been stuck on this for so long I’ll upload the working version when I have time but either way, keep trying until I do it!

Comment: No need... just fixed it! What a pain that was. Thanks again for all of your help, I don’t think many people would have helped me through it to the degree that you did!

Comment: I’m so glad you figured it out! Good luck with your app!!!